# What does "relocation offered" mean exactly on Careers?

Tags: discussion, jobs

What does "relocation offered" exactly mean? Is it about sponsoring visa/work permit? I have seen many positions indicating "relocation offered" but then mentioning that applicants must be [I guess already] eligible to live and work in that country.

I think it would be really helpful to be able to filter results based on sponsoring visa, like HN "Who is hiring?" posts. [It has also been [discussed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72475/careers-finding-offers-that-might-consider-visa-sponsorship).]

Comment: The last sentence you just edited it is really a separate thing. You should search to see if it's been requested already, or post a new feature-request if not, if you like.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I have already searched for "relocation offered", I will search for it and remove it if it already has been discussed.

Comment: @AndrewBarber edited.

Comment: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/8996/what-can-relocation-assistance-entail

Comment: @ColinD its about careers.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @JohnS I deleted my comment before the reply, but 'relocation offered' is a pretty generic job hunting term, that's why I commented about migration.

Answer (score 18):

"Relocation offered" generally refers to an employer being willing to consider paying moving expenses and providing other considerations to enable a new hire to move there. It usually does not include things related to those not already eligible to work in the country in question.

Comment: Should this question be here ? or is it here because the question is asked in respect of http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ ?

Comment: @Habib: yes, that's what the [careers] tag is for (it doesn't have a separate Meta site.)

Comment: Does it mean paying moving expenses for an interview?

Comment: @yannishristofakis No, it doesn't.