# Is it that only way to find if company is interested in sponsoring visa only by applying them?

Tags: discussion, jobs

'Relocation Offered' tag is not providing any information. I understand it includes moving expenses but does it include visa too?

**This question is different** from

- [Careers: finding offers that might consider visa sponsorship](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72475/careers-finding-offers-that-might-consider-visa-sponsorship), and
- [What does “relocation offered” mean exactly on Careers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194375/what-does-relocation-offered-mean-exactly-on-careers)

because I want to know how to find out visa sponsorship details? **Is it implicit or we need to ask company explicitly in application.**

Is it that only way to find if company is interested in sponsoring visa only by applying them?

Comment: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/sponsorship

Comment: It is implicit/default sponsorship is not offered

Answer (score 4):

Relocation Offered **DOES NOT** imply visa sponsorship. If you have any questions you'd need to contact the employer.